# delete/modify an edge in graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

is there any way to delete an existing edge in a graph?
For example, when I draw an edge using

```
self.g.edge('a', 'b')
```

where self.g is my digraph, then I do

```
self.g.edge('a', 'b', _attributes={'arrowhead': 'dot'})
```

it draws another edge from a->b so now there are 2 edges instead of 1

basically what I'm trying to do is modify the existing edge

it works for nodes, but not edges

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: graphviz  pip install graphviz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can delete or modify anything with this library, but you can avoid multiple edges by initializing the graph with `Digraph(strict=True)` or similar.

The reason it seems to work for nodes is that Graphviz itself replaces an existing node if a new one with the same name is added later.

Comment: yeah :( couldn't find anything either